# Can't switch users on MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I use a web hosting with CPanel. In MySQL Databases tool I've created a user - "realuser_user1" and granted all privileges on database realuser_Goods. In phpMyAdmin I've logged in as realuser@localhost(I think it's the same username which the host provider sent to me but with this "@localhost" for some reason) and I want to switch to realuser_user1, so I type in console,

> mysql -u realuser_user1 -p

(I press Ctrl-Enter)
Pop up a window with 4 errors:

1. Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "mysql" at position 0)
2. Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "u" at position 7)
3. Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "website1_user1" at position 9)
4. Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "p" at position 25)

#1064 - Number of the error

What do I do wrong?

Comment: MySQL is a program which must be executed from shell, not from MySQL CLI.

Comment: I don't have mysql on my laptop. How can I use mysql on the web server?

Comment: You must edit configuration settings/file (or connection codeblock of your program)  for an application which connects to MySQL and specify new username. Then reconnect.

Comment: If I want to  change  a user in phpMyAdmin I need to edit config.ini.php file?

Comment: config.inC.php !

Answer (score 0):

`mysql -u realuser_user1 -p` is a shell command, so it's not mean to be run as an SQL command through the phpMyAdmin SQL tab. In order to connect as a different user, you should present that other user login information at the login prompt when connecting to phpMyAdmin (or, if for some reason you are using the 'config' authentication type, you would edit the settings stored in the configuration file `config.inc.php`). In a hosted situation, it's unlikely that you'll have access — or need — to change the configuration file, though.

When logging in to phpMyAdmin, you don't need to provide the hostname part of the user account. This is determined by the connection type and hostname during the connection process; so if you're connecting as username `realuser_user1` through a socket connection it looks up the MySQL user account having User `realuser_user1` and Host `localhost`. A connection for `root` through a TCP/IP connection (even if it's connecting to 127.0.0.1, which is "localhost" in the *networking sense*) looks up the account for `root` with Host `%` or `127.0.0.1`. It's rather common shorthand to simplify the connection information by writing "root@localhost" but that isn't meant literally, it's shorthand for the two values of "User" and "Host". You can even see that shortened form on the phpMyAdmin main page where it shows the User: field.

In phpMyAdmin, you can see on the main page the connection type (in the right hand side, it's the first item under "Database server", for instance mine reads `Server: Localhost via UNIX socket`. This indicates that my user is connected with Host localhost, so any additional user I want to connect as needs to have localhost privileges. If I needed to connect as a user that has only `%` or `127.0.0.1` Host privileges, I would need to edit my configuration file `config.inc.php` to change the connect_type from 'socket' to 'tcp'. For security purposes, though, it's generally best to restrict users as much as possible, so I stick to socket connections for the most part.

So to solve your problem, you should try logging in as `realuser_user1` instead of `realuser_user1@localhost`. If that doesn't work, check your phpMyAdmin page to see from which host you're connecting, log in as your administrative user and create an additional user or change the host for `realuser_user1` to match (again, I suggest using the most restrictive hostname or IP address you can).